# How do I remove a device from a free (un-enrolled) team provisioning profile?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I'm writing a React Native app for iOS and Android. After building the project through Xcode onto three different (physical) devices, the product owner wanted a version for testing on his personal iPhone as well. Now, when building to his device, Xcode simply spits out a few red lines, which seem to occur from the same error:

> Unable to add device (device-name-here) because the team has already
>   reached the maximum number of iPhone devices.

Then something about that the build can't commence, because the device is not registered in the team profile etc.

**I realize I'm using a free provisioning profile, but I was not warned about the device limitation beforehand, which makes me think I can change which devices are connected to the profile somehow. Am I misunderstanding something? Or how do I go about doing this?**

As of now, I won't have access to an enrolled developer account, so I'm having to make do with a free one. This is my first time working with Apple software, coming from a long streak of Android development and open source software.

Comment: I have this problem in Xcode 9, and when I look at my device list, it doesn't show a list of devices for the profile. It only shows the current, connected device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The free developer program has a 3 device limit. To increase the number of devices, you'll need to purchase a membership, which will increase the limit to 100. You can only reset your list of registered devices on your annual renewal cycle.

Comment: Is this limit in writing anywhere? -TIA